# htaccess complex rule for product searcher

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to create a complex rules for my product searcher. 3 rules, 4 or more values each.

---

The clean URL should look like this:

**www.domain.com/products/rule1-value4/rule2-value5/rule3-value2**

---

The orginal URL look like this:

**www.domain.com/products?rule1[ ]=4&rule2[ ]=5&rule3[ ]=2**

---

Of course, a combination of policies is arbitrary, there aren't always 3 so the htaccess Rules should be universal. There are too many possible combinations to do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^products/rule1-value3/?$ /products?rule1[]=3 [L]
```

I start to create complex rule which rewrite each rule and glue the url together on the last line (for two rules and 1 value each for test). And it doesn't work. Please help. I'm so lame in complicated htaccess rules and regular expresions :)

```
RewriteRule ^/products/?(.*)?(rule1-value1)(.*)? %{REQUEST_URI}?rule1[]=1 [QSA]    
RewriteRule ^/products/?(.*)?(rule2-value3)(.*)? %{REQUEST_URI}?rule2[]=3 [QSA]    
RewriteRule ^/products/^(.*)$ /products$1 [QSA,L]
```